# Searching for text mining/extraction software with Intuitive, Modern UI

Tags: bigdata, analytics, text-mining, text-analysis

I'm researching different products for my organization. We are looking for a solution that will replace our current text mining software - DataWatch Monarch. We need some type of software that will be able to extract only relevant data from PDF reports and prepare it to be stored in a database.

DataWatch is causing a bottleneck for our organization due to learning curve and limitations. I started to try and do this just by programming using R, however, we need a more streamlined approach.

If you know of any easy to use, highly effective, text miners or report-text-extractor-like software please share. I will be looking into Scribe Software, SiMX, RapidMiner, and some others.

Comment: I have a decent amount of experience with Scribe and I don't think it has the functionality to extract data from a PDF format. It could be a new feature though.

Answer (score 1):

RapidMiner can extract info from PDFs no problem using the Text Processing extension. Start with the Read Document operator and go from there.

[image]

Storing in a database is also straightforward - set up your database connection in the "Manage Database Connections" menu and then use the "Write Database" operator.

[image]

[image]